# Dynamic Geometry Software for teach construction

Tags: geometry, education, geometric-construction

I would like to know about a software that will help me show construction steps to the students with using a Compass/Straight Edge/Protractor/Divider. Here is example video below.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NzcTKGxwCCE

Comment: @Amzoti  But using geogebra can we show compass, protractor, etc. like the video. Here see this http://www.mathopenref.com/constcopyangle.html I want to do it using a software, myself.

Comment: @amzoti Thanks a lot.

Comment: You might also ask about this on http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/ or perhaps even http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ *if* this post here yields no result in reasonable time. But please don't cross-post just now, wait a few days for an answer here then try *one* alternative next, adding links between the questions.

Comment: Try this: www.euclidraw.com. It can do dynamic constructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tabula](http://numeracyworks.com/) looks like it might fit you requirements, but I only briefly looked at the screenshots:

[image]

[image]

I found it after scanning [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_interactive_geometry_software) for "extras".  Maybe you'll find more there.